# SBT project compile time only dependency

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, task

I'm trying to create a custom task that will generate some extra sources for me. To do this, I need two different libraries `A` and `A-runtime`.

`A` is just a compile time dependency to be able to generate the source files. The `A-runtime` is also needed as a runtime dependency.

Including `A-runtime` is easy by just including it in the library dependencies as:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.organization" % "A-runtime" % "version"
```

Since I don't want the `A` library to be included in the runtime dependencies, I tried to create a new ivyConfiguration for this as:

```
ivyConfigurations += config("compileonly").hide
```

and included the library as:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.organization" % "A" % "version" % "compileonly"
```

I then defined the new task in the `Build.scala` as:

```
lazy val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("description")
val customTaskSettings = Seq(
  customTask := {
      com.organization.Generator.run()
  }
)


lazy val myProject = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(customTaskSettings)
```

Now however, SBT can no longer open the project because it cannot find `com.organization.Generator`. Which makes sense because at the time SBT is compiling `Build.scala` it does not have the dependency on `A`.

Now I know that any SBT project is simply another scala project, but is there a way to add the `A` library as a dependency to the SBT project?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know that any SBT project is simply another scala project, but is there a way to add the A library as a dependency to the SBT project?

The dependencies of the SBT project itself must be defined in `project/build.sbt` or `project/project/Build.scala`, not in `project/Build.scala`. And you don't want that dependency to be compile-time only, since you need to run it to execute `customTask`.